# get task of ant not downloading the complete war file

Tags: ant, get, task

I am trying to download a war file from another machine using get task, below are the scripts -

```
<get src="http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:8080/job/workboat-server/ws/NSMobile/target/NSMobile.war" 
            dest="${sw-in-house}/NSMobile/NSMobile.war" 
            username="username"
            password="password"/>
```

where ${sw-in-house} is a directory where I want to download the NSMobile war. Now the problem is, above script is downloading just half of the file. The actual size of the file is 116MB but the file which is getting downloaded is just 80MB. Can anyone help me out with this? For your information, when I am trying to call this ant script directly(i.e. externally) then it works as expected but only when I am trying to call it through Jenkins, it is downloading the incomplete file.

Comment: Can you post Jenkins o/p which is causing the problem along with the configuration?
Also did you try to execute in verbose mode for debug? ant -v -f build.xml ?

Comment: It is not showing any error actually, it just downloads the half file, this issue is coming while calling the ant scripts in Jenkins only. When I am trying to run this externally with or without verbose it always works.

Comment: it will be difficult to troubleshoot without getting any logs. Verbose should give you some insight why its not downloading complete file.